# C# - Nome da propriedade de instância em um DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Possuo uma classe `Produtos` com os seguintes atributos:

```
public class Produto
{
    public int cod { get; set; }
    public string codBarras { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public Categoria categoria { get; set; }
    public Decimal precoCompra { get; set; }
    public Decimal precoVenda { get; set; }
    public Decimal qtdEstoque { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }

}
```

A classe `Categoria` está da seguinte maneira:

```
 public class Categoria
{
    public int cod { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
}
```

Quando desejo listar os produtos em um `DataGridView`, quero que as linhas de `Produtos` tenham na coluna `Categoria` com a propriedade `nome` da instância da classe `Categoria` que está dentro da instância do `Produto`.

Mas está aparecendo assim na hora de listar os produtos no DataGridView:
[image]

Propriedade da coluna "Categoria" nas propriedades do `DataGridView`:
[image]

Como as instâncias de Produto estão sendo criadas no SELECT que faço no banco de dados :

```
Produto prod = new Produto();
prod....(outros campos)
prod.categoria = CategoriaDAO.getCategoria(leitorSQL.GetInt32("codCategoria"));
```

Este método getCategoria() retorna uma instância da classe Categoria de acordo com o código da categoria de um produto.

Algumas perguntas:

1 - Existe a possibilidade de fazer isso?

2 - É uma boa prática de programação colocar que(neste exemplo) os objetos do tipo `Produto` possuem um atributo do tipo `Categoria`? Ou seria melhor criar duas variáveis? Sendo uma para o código da categoria e outra para o nome da `Categoria`.

Comment: uma opção é você definir a coluna como `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, e fazer o bind pelo código da categoria, você pode manter a aparência de um TextBox nas opções da coluna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa resposta eu acabei colando do SO em inglês mesmo, do seguinte post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10567944/276960

Em geral, parece que o DataGridView não tem nada pronto para fazer isso. Mas sua montagem de objeto esta perfeita (principalmente se você trabalhar com EntityFramework).

O SO em inglês deu uma solução interessante usando um evento do DataGridView de formatação e dando o resultado quando você usar objetos dentro de objetos:

```
private void Grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    DataGridViewRow row = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DataGridViewColumn col = grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (row.DataBoundItem != null && col.DataPropertyName.Contains("."))
    {
        string[] props = col.DataPropertyName.Split('.');
        PropertyInfo propInfo = row.DataBoundItem.GetType().GetProperty(props[0]);
        object val = propInfo.GetValue(row.DataBoundItem, null);
        for (int i = 1; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            propInfo = val.GetType().GetProperty(props[i]);
            val = propInfo.GetValue(val, null);
        }
        e.Value = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu vou marcar como resposta pois peguei este codigo que vc enviou e coloquei no evento cell_formatting da minha dgv e funcionou exatamente como eu precisava em todos os casos . Obrigado!